# Subtracting Decimal Values (Assembly)

Tags: linux, assembly, floating-point, x86

How do I subtract a decimal value in **assembly**. IA32 (linux)

```
1:       mov edx, 1/2   
         sub ecx, ebx
         sub ecx, edx
         mov bal2, ecx
```

I tried this but it some how skips the subtraction with the decimal.
And if I enter **.5** it gives me an error.

> error:junk `.5' after expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As lightbulbone correctly says in his answer, you cannot work on floating point values when using general purpose registers (`eax` etc.). You could use the FPU, as lightbulbone suggests, but that is comparatively tedious.

Alternatively - unless your code needs to run on ancient CPUs -  you can use the SSE instructions for this task, which is much more straightforward. Code similar to what you are showing might look like the following:

```
.data 
  OneHalf dd 0.5
  bal2 dd ?
.code
  movss xmm0, OneHalf  ; instead of mov edx, 1/2
  subss xmm1, xmm2     ; instead of sub ecx, ebx
  subss xmm1, xmm0     ; instead of sub ecx, edx
  movss bal2, xmm1     ; instead of mov bal2, ecx
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided is not capable of subtracting a "decimal value".  I am assuming that by "decimal value" you really mean floating-point value, in which case you can not use the integer arithmetic facilities as you've done.

I highly recommend you download the Intel IA-64 Architecture Software Developer's Manual ([Intel IA-64 Architecture Software Developer's Mnaul](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/manuals/)) and have a read through the sections that explain how to use the x87 floating-point facilities.  Specifically, look at:

- Volume 1, Section 5.2
- Volume 1, Chapter 8
- Volume 2A, Section 3.2

As a word of caution, my experience with the floating-point facilities is quite minimal.  However, my understanding is that it is a stack based environment in which you can load (push) an item on to the stack and then operate on it.  The commands I would look at are: FLD, FSUB, and FST (all are listed in Volume 2A).

As an example, here is a short program that loads +1 and the constant pi into the floating-point stack then performs the operation pi-1 and pops the result.

```
/* floating point subtraction */

    .text
    .globl _main
```

_main:
        pushq   %rbp
        movq    %rsp, %rbp

```
    fld1    /* load +1.0 */
    fldpi   /* load pi (3.14159...) */
    fsubp   /* 3.14159 - 1.0, pop result */

    movq    $0x0, %rax
    leave
    ret
```

Comment: P doesn't pop to *ax, it just frees it from floating point stack.

Comment: On the other hand, **movq    $0x0, %rax** might just be your return value.